# MongoDB OR with Regex not using compound index

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

Really at wits end here; I'm using the following query to search a collection with about 300K documents

```
query = { $or: [
  {description: { $regex: ".*app.*"}},
  {username: { $regex: ".*app.*"}}, 
]};
```

and simply putting that in a .find() function. It is tremendously slow. Like every single query takes at least 20 seconds.

I have tried individual indices on both username and description, and now have a compound index on {description: 1, username: 1}, but it does not seem to make a difference at all. If I check the MongoDB live metrics, it does not use the index at all.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like incorrect expressions. Can you paste some sample documents and correct query?

Comment: Hi Amit. It does return documents, it is just very slow. There are only three fields in the document. Username, description, and followers.

Comment: use explain to see if you index is being used correctly by mongo

Comment: I figured out the problem, and it's pretty obvious; because I'm using a partial string matching regex, it can't use the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex using partial string matching never use an index, because, as the name implies, with a partial string match it has no idea where to start looking for the match, and has to go over all strings.

As a solution, you can hook your database up to something like Lucene, which specializes in such queries.